# Delete rows in data frame if entry appears fewer than x times

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, delete-row

I have the following data frame, call it df, which is a data frame consisting in three vectors: "Name," "Age," and "ZipCode."

```
df=      
  Name Age ZipCode
1  Joe  16   60559
2  Jim  20   60637
3  Bob  64   94127
4  Joe  23   94122
5  Bob  45   25462
```

I want to delete the entire row of `df` if the `Name` in it appears fewer than 2 times in the data frame as a whole (and flexibly 3, 4, or x times).  Basically keep `Bob` and `Joe` in the data frame, but delete `Jim`.  How can I do this?

I tried to turn it into a table:

```
> table(df$Name)

Bob Jim Joe 
 2   1   2
```

But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ave` like this:

```
df[as.numeric(ave(df$Name, df$Name, FUN=length)) >= 2, ]
#   Name Age ZipCode
# 1  Joe  16   60559
# 3  Bob  64   94127
# 4  Joe  23   94122
# 5  Bob  45   25462
```

This answer assumes that `df$Name` is a `character` vector, not a `factor` vector.

---

You can also continue with `table` as follows:

```
x <- table(df$Name)
df[df$Name %in% names(x[x >= 2]), ]
#   Name Age ZipCode
# 1  Joe  16   60559
# 3  Bob  64   94127
# 4  Joe  23   94122
# 5  Bob  45   25462
```

Comment: First one works, but the second one is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Mlee, No problem. You can also explore the "data.table" package, which will let you do things like: `library(data.table); DT <- data.table(df); DT[, count := .N, by = Name][count >= 2]`.

Comment: ...or shorter data.table version, with credit to @mnel - `DT[, if(.N >= 2) .SD, by=Name]`

Comment: @thelatemail, nice one!